# Dawes Super Galaxy - Tubes

Tags: innertube

I picked up a near new Dawes Galaxy that had been in storage for 8 years. I'm super excited to get on a tour. I have both Lands End to John O'Groats and London to Paris locked in:)

The tires are marked `Schwalbe Marathon 32 - 622 (28 x 15/8 x 1 1/4 - 700 x 32c) hs308`. Tube markings have always confused me, and I'm sure it gets asked here all the time.

What tube should I be looking at here in the UK as a spare?

Will [this one](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Raleigh-Inner-Tube-700x28-32C/dp/B004TGL21M/ref=sr_1_8?s=sports&ie=UTF8&qid=1393250378&sr=1-8&keywords=700x28-32c) be OK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the number most usually listed is 700x32, so anything with that in the range will be the right size. You can even get away with slightly bigger or smaller tubes in a pinch.

The ones you linked to should be fine, or try [these from Schwalbe](http://www.wiggle.co.uk/schwalbe-road-inner-tube/). Some people recommend Schwalbe for reliable tubes as well as tyres.

Note valves: It might matter whether you currently have [Schrader (like a car tyre) or Presta](http://sheldonbrown.com/brandt/presta-schrader.html) valves. If you have presta, the Schrader tube valves might not fit through the hole in the rim. Probably simplest to get the same kind.

Comment: 700x32 isn't in that link you sent. Did you mean `700 x 28/42`?

Comment: Well, 32 is between 28 and 42, so well within the range.

Comment: Ah OK thanks. It's all so unnecessarily complicated:)

Comment: I found [these](http://www.halfords.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/product_storeId_10001_catalogId_10151_productId_920311_langId_-1_categoryId_242552) which should be as good a price as any. Although I don't think the picture matches the description. The box says 18 and the details say 28.